# Is the Eye of Sauron an artifact: similar to the Ring or to a Palantir?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, sauron

In the trilogy, **The Lord of the Rings**, Tolkien describes Sauron's fortress of Barad-dûr as having a high tower, within which there exists the *Eye of Sauron*.

> *In the black abyss there appeared a single Eye that slowly grew, until it filled nearly all the Mirror. So terrible was it that Frodo stood rooted, unable to cry out or to withdraw his gaze. The Eye was rimmed with fire, but was itself glazed, yellow as a cat's, watchful and intent, and the black slit of its pupil opened on a pit, a window into nothing.
>
>   [The Fellowship of the Ring, Book II, Chapter 8]*

And throughout the story, there are scattered references to *the lidless eye* in connection with Sauron. The Lord of the Nazgul, for instance, warns Dernhelm -

> *'Come not between the Nazgûl and his prey! Or he will not slay thee in thy turn. He will bear thee away to the houses of lamentation, beyond all darkness, where thy flesh shall be devoured, and thy shriveled mind be left naked to the Lidless Eye.'*

Frodo physically possesses an Elven artifact, the Ring, which confers upon its bearer a power to see things from far away, as he experiences upon Amon Hen at the conclusion of Book II. In *The Two Towers* Sauron, Saruman and Denethor all possess Elven artifacts, the surviving *palantíri*, which confer upon their keeper a power to see far away. Gandalf refers to other Elven artifacts of power, the Silmarils stolen by Morgoth in the First Age; and he turns out to possess, himself, one of the Three Rings of the Elven Kings. And Galadriel has yet another Elven artifact with the power to see far away: namely, the Mirror of Galadriel.

Is the *Eye of Sauron* an Elven artifact, obtained or stolen by Sauron in the Elder Days? Like the Ring, it evidently confers a power to see far away (for Sauron uses it thus, at a time when he no longer possesses the Ring). But I am not as familiar with *The Silmarillion*, or *Unfinished Tales*, or *The History of Middle Earth*, or *The Letters of JRR Tolkien* as I am with the trilogy.

I am *not* asking whether the Eye is a real object rather than a metaphor. For myself, I am satisfied that it is *not* a metaphor, for Frodo sees it as an actual object, in the Mirror of Galadriel: in the passage I have quoted above, both the Mirror and the Eye appear to be real objects having a physical existence.

Is there evidence, *anywhere* in the writings of Professor Tolkien, which casts light on the nature, or origin, of the *lidless eye*? Is it in fact an artifact? If so, is it Elvish in origin (like the Silmarils, the *palantíri*, the Mirror of Galadriel, and the Elven Rings)?

Is there any suggestion that Sauron's power to see far away derives simply from his possession of the Ithil Stone (rather than being an innate power of the *Eye of Sauron*)?

Comment: I think that the Eye *is* Sauron.

Comment: The One Ring is not an Elven artifact, Sauron forged it separately from the rings Celebrimbor fashioned

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn - Noted, but Sauron had stolen or acquired the secret (of how the Great Rings were made) from Celebrimbor.

Comment: @Ed999 No, other way 'round. Celebrimbor learned everything he knew about making magic rings from Sauron; that's why the Three were also bound up in the power of the One

Comment: @ed999 Sauron taught Celebrimbor (and the other smiths of Eregion) the secret of ring making. Celebrimbor not fully deceived by Sauron made the 3 without Saurons knowledge

Comment: That edit should be a different question.

Comment: Not sure why Frodo seeing the eye in Galadriel's mirror would preclude it from being a metaphor. In the same way that tarot cards use concrete figures to describe abstract concepts, it's reasonable to understand the images in her mirror as symbolic.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to believe that the One Ring "confers upon its bearer a power to see things from far away." Amon Hen, we're told, means "The Hill of Sight", and Aragorn at least plans to "see what may be seen" (Book II chapter 10). Nor does it appear clear to me that the Eye is physical at all.

Comment: The one ring does not give the power to see a long way. That was some ancient magic, used to help the border guards.

Comment: I'm relying on the following passage for the statement that Celebrimbor's secrets were stolen by Sauron: "Elrond .. told of the Elven-smiths of Eregion and their friendship with Moria, and their eagerness for knowledge, by which Sauron ensnared them. For in that time he was not yet evil to behold, and they received his aid and grew mighty in craft, whereas he learned all their secrets, and betrayed them, and forged secretly in the Mountain of Fire the One Ring to be their master. But Celebrimbor was aware of him, and hid the Three which he had made...

Comment: you mean it's not a literal eye in the top of an enormous tower?????

Comment: @sgroves: Not clear whether you intend that ironically or not. For those in doubt,the film image is foreign to the books.

Comment: Backing up @HarrisWeinstein, we are told that the mirror shows possibilities, not necessarily reality, and the images in the mirror also switch from time to time. I certainly discount what Frodo sees in the mirror as telling us anything of the nature of the Eye.

Comment: Galadriel, when she explains her Mirror to Sam, means simply what she says, that some events never come to pass unless the person who looks in the Mirror turns aside from his path because of what the Mirror has revealled. She offers a choice of possible futures, depending upon what Sam - or whoever does the looking - does next. But she is not saying that what the Mirror shows is unreality, only that Sam has two futures: what he sees either will or will not come to pass, depending whether or not he turns aside from the quest. It "mirrors" the choice she offered Sam at their first meeting. :-)

Comment: All those examples are _visions_.

Comment: It remains ambiguous as to whether the Eye is meant to represent an artifact, or is literally Sauron's eye. But, inevitably, the scenes shown by the Mirror of Galadriel are _visions_ (of the future) -- what else could they be? But this does not mean the Mirror is projecting unreality. It simply shows what _will_ (in the future) be.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### No, there is no evidence for this

You're just going to have to trust me on that; the nature of the Eye of Sauron is never really discussed in any kind of satisfying detail. Whatever physical component [may exist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/127272/31051) is likely related to one or more concepts:

- Sauron's enhanced powers as a Maia
- The *palantír* of Minas Ithil, in Sauron's possession

If the *palantír* is a component of the Eye<sup>1</sup> (which seems likely, though, again, there's no direct evidence for this), then it's (at least partially) an artifact in that sense. However, there is no reason to suspect that the Eye is a separate item from the Elder days.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [Shamshiel's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149143/31051) for more on this

Comment: I thought it's heavily implied that the "eye of Sauron" is his Maia use of the palantir, which allows him to see across Middle Earth.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was clear that the "eye of Sauron" referred to Sauron's attention and gaze through the palantir he seized from Minas Ithil.

Comment: @Shamshiel I don't entirely disagree, though I do think the Eye has more nuanced meaning in different contexts (as I've expounded on elsewhere), but I was focusing on different parts of the question. I've edited somewhat, but I think your answer makes a detailed discussion somewhat redundant

Comment: Isn't it also a heraldic symbol, like the Hand of Saruman or the White Tree of Gondor?

Answer (score 39):

I think you've actually answered your own question.

> In The Two Towers Sauron, Saruman and Denethor all possess Elven artifacts, the surviving palantíri, which confer upon their keeper a power to see far away.

As you say, Sauron possesses the palantir, which allows someone of sufficiently strong will to see (almost) anything, (almost) anywhere. The easiest, and most logical explanation, is that the "Eye of Sauron" is at times a metaphor for Sauron's use of the palatir, and other times, as when Frodo looks into the Mirror of Galadriel, *literally Sauron's eye looking into the palantir.*

> Is there any suggestion that Sauron's power to see far away derives simply from his possession of the Ithil Stone?

Mostly just Occam's Razor. The 'Eye of Sauron' was never referred to prior to Sauron's takeover of Minas Ithil. We are told that Sauron's gaze is particularly *terrible*, but there's no reason to believe he had a supernatural ability to see faraway events.

> Now Gorlim would have drawn back, but daunted by the eyes of Sauron he told at last all that he would know.
> (Silmarillion)

Sauron is a sorceror, an illusionist, a torturer, a shape-changer, a teacher, a bringer-of-gifts, a priest, but never is there a reference to omniscience. Nor would it make much sense for an embodied Ainur to be omniscient.

Then, as you say, Sauron is known to be in possession of a palantir. We know not only that he has it, but that he uses it *often*: Denethor and Saruman almost cannot use their palantirs without communicating with Sauron.

> ‘In this way Denethor gained his great knowledge of things that passed in his realm, and far beyond his borders, at which men marvelled; but he bought the knowledge dearly, being aged before his time by his contest with the will of Sauron. Thus pride increased in Denethor together with despair, until he saw in all the deeds of that time only a single combat between the Lord of the White Tower and the Lord of the Barad-dûr, and mistrusted all others who resisted Sauron, unless they served himself alone.
> (LotR, Appendix A)

Keep in mind that almost the very minute Pippin looked in the Stone, Sauron was there.

> In a low hesitating voice Pippin began again, and slowly his words grew clearer and stronger. ‘I saw a dark sky, and tall battlements,’ he said. ‘And tiny stars. It seemed very far away and long ago, yet hard and clear. Then the stars went in and out - they were cut off by things with wings. Very big, I think, really; but in the glass they looked like bats wheeling round the tower. I thought there were nine of them. One began to fly straight towards me, getting bigger and bigger. It had a horrible - no, no! I can't say.
>
> ‘I tried to get away, because I thought it would fly out; but when it had covered all the globe, it disappeared. Then he came. He did not speak so that I could hear words. He just looked, and I understood.
> (LotR, The Two Towers)

Similarly, Sauron is right there when Aragorn uses the stone to trick him, and we're told that the reason that using the stone is dangerous is precisely because Sauron possesses the Ithil stone.

So given that we know that Sauron *has* a stone which lets him see far away, and he's constantly using the stone that lets him see far away, the easy conclusion to come to is the all-seeing Eye of Sauron is Sauron's Eye, looking through the palantir.

As a final note, consider how Denethor's use of the palantir was described:

> 'It was in the very hour that Faramir was brought to the Tower that many of us saw a strange light in the topmost chamber,’ said Beregond. ‘But we have seen that light before, and it has long been rumoured in the City that the Lord would at times wrestle in thought with his Enemy.’(lotR, RotK)

A 'strange light' at the top of a tower certainly seems reminiscent of the depictions of the Eye of Sauron.

Addendum: Frodo's visions on Amon Hen probably have more to do with the magical properties of Amon Hen, *possibly* in combination with the Ring, than the Ring alone.

Comment: Sauron was waiting for respawn in spectator mode (granted by palantir)

Comment: @Daerdemandt: Not to ruin the joke with pedantry, but Sauron had respawned long before the events of the Lord of the Rings. :)

Comment: "Sauron is known to be in possession of a palantir. We know not only that he has it, but that he uses it often: Denethor and Saruman cannot use their palantirs without communicating with Sauron." That's not entirely  accurate -From Unfinished Tales "The Palantiri "Whether Denethor ever thus made contact with the Orthanc stone and Saruman is not told; probably he did & did so with profit to himself.Sauron could not break in on these conferences :only the surveyor using the Master Stone of Osgiliath could "eavesdrop.

Comment: @turinsbane: That's a good point. I wonder though, whether the communication properties of the stone are an entirely different function and therefore Denethor could do it without Sauron's interference altogether, or whether you had to "see" someone with the stone first, requiring mental effort against Sauron, and then you could talk, which Sauron couldn't eavesdrop against because it was simply an enhanced form of 'osanwe.'

Comment: Denethor was able to make use of the Anor stone without (much) of Sauron's influence. The latter was, somehow, able to attempt to "wrench" the gaze of the Anor stone towards himself. It apparently took much strength to prevent Sauron from doing so (hence Denethor's aging, and Aragorn's comments). Presumably the same applied to Saruman with the Orthanc stone, but with less control than Denethor, as Denethor was a legitimate user of the stone.

Comment: @Jelsema: Oh, sure, but the point is that (evidently) Sauron seems to have been almost always around or holding the stone, else it wouldn't be necessary to struggle against Sauron in the first place; that also explains why Sauron 'just happened' to be using the Stone when Pippin and Aragorn used it - he always was.

Comment: I was more commenting about your phrasing "Denethor and Saruman cannot use their palantirs without communicating with Sauron". Maybe it is just a phrasing thing, but the "cannot" part makes me uneasy. If memory serves, they both could and did, but at some point both became "trapped". As to Sauron's use of the stone, Sauron "would not (and could not) have the Ithil-stone under perpetual observation." (UT, Palantiri). Just a matter of whether the others managed to jump in on those "free times" (or if, even then, too much strength was required to use the stone properly).

Comment: @Jelsema: Changed to *almost*, because I agree he can't *always* be looking at the stone; he obviously does take time to send out orders, torture Gollum, do what a Dark Lord does, etc; I just think it's clear he uses it *very* frequently*.

Comment: Sauron is an immortal, supremely powerful being. You are almost saying, 'Denethor can use the Stone whilst Sauron sleeps': but I seriously doubt Sauron ever did (do the words _sleepless malice_ ring any bells?). Sauron was spending 100 percent of his time watching events in Middle Earth, using the Eye or the Ithil Stone: he had a lieutenant, Gothmog, who ran the Barad-dur for him; and he had the Nazgul to torture his captives. Moreover, we do not know for certain the ultimate fate of the palantir of Osgiliath (after all, the Ring, too, had been thought lost in the Great River).

Comment: @Ed999: Sauron tortured Gollum in person, and Jelsema's quote from UT has a Word of God statement he wasn't using the stone literally constantly. Sure, he didn't sleep, but he still had to run his business; lieutenants can't do it all for you, especially when you're a God-King with a love for total control and order. No doubt he used it as much as he possibly could, just not 24/7.

Answer (score 12):

**It's mostly a metaphor**

As it is used across the books, the *"eye"* often refers to Sauron himself, to his power, his will or the effect he has on the world.

When seen on Galadriel's mirror, the mirror itself is showing dream-like images, and the burning eye is portrayed as a representation of Sauron's power.

The reference to *"the window of the eye"* quite possibly refers to the windows atop the dark tower from where Sauron oversees his domain and projects his power.

The movie took the metaphors relating to the *"eye"* and translated them into Sauron taking the form of a literal flaming eye, while in the books he is corporeal (Gollum has seen him in person).

As has been commented, there is no specific discussion on this subject, but the people's of Middle Earth (as well as Tolkien's descriptions) seem to be quite prone to referring to symbols and metaphors when speaking of things, particularly magical things, rather than factual definitions, which leads me to my interpretation.

As another example, see the controversy regarding whether the Balrog had wings or not, which is not very clear based solely on how the book describes it.

Comment: The Hobbit movies do end up reconciling the "literal flaming eye" with his corporeal form, as mentioned in @Mithrandir's answer.

Comment: @Random832 Sauron wasn't truly corporeal in The Hobbit movies, and Saruman states that Sauron can not take physical form in the Lord of the Rings movies. The books, on the other hand, imply that Sauron has a physical body, albeit a relatively weak one. The movies chose to be more literal with the Eye of Sauron, which works better in a visual medium.

Answer (score 9):

## Book canon:

No idea. As @JasonBaker said, this isn't really discussed.

## Movie canon:

Taken from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/27658/33591):

> In The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug, the pupil of the great eye is shown to be the fiery silhouette of Sauron.

So it would appear that the Eye is fire surrounding Sauron, which gives the appearance of a giant eye.

See [this gif](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/lotr/images/1/16/Sauron_in_DOS.gif/revision/latest?cb=20131229043229), which shows him appearing like the pupil in an eye made of flame.

Answer (score 4):

In the chapter *Mount Doom*, in *The Return of the King*, there is evidence that the eye is physical artifact:

> Thence, turning and encircling all its [the path up Mount Doom] wide girth from south to north, it climbed at last, high in the upper cone, but still far from the reeking summit, to a dark entrance that gazed back east straight to the Window of the Eye in Sauron's shadow-mantled fortress.

I argue that either:

1. The Eye is a physical, stationary artifact placed in it's own window, or
2. The Eye is actually that of Sauron's when he looks out onto the path of Mount Doom, in which case the window is only special that it is pointing in a certain direction

My own interpretation is in line with point 1. I support the first conclusion because of the capitalisation in the quote. It is the Eye, not the eye. Also, it is the Window, not the window. From [the answer to Why Did J.R.R. Tolkien Capitalize Certain Words Throughout His Books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/27053/53308):

> Tolkien is capitalizing words that refer to proper nouns or concepts that would unceremoniously get capitalization if expressed directly.

Therefore, the Window and Eye are not normal windows or eyes.

Comment: What leads you to go with (1) rather than (2)?

Comment: The Eye of Sauron is literally the eye of Sauron.

Comment: @MattGutting and Verdan: edited the answer. It's based on the use of capitals implying they are not mundane windows or eyes.

Comment: The use of capitals implies (as the answer you quote states) that this is a proper noun, and important in some way - not that it's a physical artifact (just as "The Shadow" isn't a physical artifact or even a literal object). I don't see any reason to believe that the Eye of Sauron is any different.

Comment: @MattGutting by that logic, since only one eye is mentioned, Sauron is likely to be a one-eyed creature! `... there appeared a single Eye that slowly grew, until it filled nearly all the Mirror` notice also that _**M**irror_ is capitalized, denoting that physical artifacts are indeed as important as other proper nouns or concepts.