# What is Sauron's true appearance?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, sauron, the-one-ring

[This question about the Eye of Sauron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127272/was-the-eye-of-sauron-a-physical-or-metaphorical-manifestation-of-saurons-will) made me wonder about Sauron's true appearance. According to the answers there, the big red eye on top of the tower is partly metaphorical but also a physical thing that exists because of Sauron's evil soul.

> There he took up again his great Ring in Barad-dûr, and dwelt there, dark and silent, until he wrought himself a new guise, **an image of malice and hatred made visible**; and the Eye of Sauron the Terrible few could endure.

The Silmarillion, Akallabeth

[image]

During the movies, we never see his true self before he was killed by Isildur. He always has his armor on in the movies. I am not sure if that was because the movie crew were unsure of his true appearance, didn't want to show it, or something else.

[image]

Sauron had an attractive physical appearance and offered to help the elves make Rings of Power during the Second Age.

Does he have a true form in the Second Age? Or did he have the ability to change his appearance at will? Which means he might not have one specific form.

I am looking for answers from the books or descriptions by Tolkien.

Comment: It appears I've wielded my powers carelessly and had the wrong link copied in my clipboard. I meant to insert this link: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27657/was-the-eye-of-sauron-saurons-actual-physical-form I've flagged to see if the mods can change it

Comment: His "true form" was a bodiless spirit.  Like all Ainur he could take physical form when he wanted and had a great deal of freedom on what he looked like (until the fall of Numenor, when he lost the ability to take 'fair form').

Comment: @suchiuomizu - Apparently he's the most beautiful being on middle-Earth. So I assume he looks something like me.